# swift property observer on reference property

Tags: swift, properties

How do you get a reference property to trigger a property observer?

In order to demonstrate my problem I wrote a simple MVC program with one button and one label. The button increments a counter in the model  and displays the value of the counter in the label in the view controller.

The problem is that the counter increment (in the model) does not trigger the didSet observer ( in the view controller)

Here is the model file:

```
import Foundation

class MvcModel {
    var counter: Int
    var message: String

    init(counter: Int, message: String) {
        self.counter = counter
        self.message = message
    }
}

// create instance
var model = MvcModel(counter: 0, message: "" )

// counting
func incrementCounter() {
    model.counter += 1
    model.message = "Counter Value:  \(model.counter)"
    //print(model.message)
}
```

Here is the view controller file:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {

    let model1 = model

    var messageFromModel = model.message {
        didSet {
            updateDisplayCounterLabel()
        }
    }

    // update Label
    func updateDisplayCounterLabel() {
        DisplayCounterLabel.stringValue = model1.message
    }

    // Label
    @IBOutlet weak var DisplayCounterLabel: NSTextField! {
        didSet {
            DisplayCounterLabel.stringValue = "counter not started"
        }
    }

    // Button
    @IBAction func IncrementButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
        incrementCounter()
        print("IBAction:  \(model1.message)")
    }
}
```

I guess the problem is linked to reference property (as I have been able to make this program work with a model based on a struct).

I would appreciate if someone could tell me how to deal with property observers and reference property and make this kind of MVC work as I plan to use it in real programs.

Comment: Please post solutions as answers not as updates to your question. This is to help future visitors understand and to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a delegate for `MvcModel`

```
protocol MvcModelDelegate {
    func didUpdateModel(counter:Int)
}
```

next you add a delegate property to `MvcModel`

```
class MvcModel {
    var counter: Int {
        didSet {
            delegate?.didUpdateModel(counter: counter)
        }
    }

    var message: String
    var delegate: MvcModelDelegate?

    init(counter: Int, message: String) {
        self.counter = counter
        self.message = message
    }
}
```

then you make the `ViewController` class conform to `MvcModelDelegate` and finally you set `model.delegate = self` into the `viewDidLoad`

```
class Controller: UIViewController, MvcModelDelegate {

    let model = MvcModel(counter: 0, message: "hello")

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.model.delegate = self
    }

    func didUpdateModel(counter: Int) {
        print("new value for counter \(counter)")
    }

}
```

Comment: @Noam I have edited both the model and the ViewController file according to what you suggested. I am not familiar with Protocol and delegate (since I am just starting programming). So I am not sure that I made the right edits. In any case the program compile but the label is not updated and the console just displays IBAction: hello. I need to go back to my books and understand the logic.

Comment: @C.Merger My code was just an example. You need to replace `print("new value for counter \(counter)")` with something like `self.myTextLabel.text = counter.description`

Comment: @Noam Yes this is what I understood. It looks like the didUpdateModel function is not called when the counter is updated.

Comment: @Noam - I've found my error. Now the label gets updated. The only remaining problem is that the value displayed in the label is the previous value, not the current one. As soon as I fix that i'll post the code.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested here is the code as suggested by Noam.

Model File:

```
    import Foundation

    protocol MvcModelDelegate {
        func didUpDateModel(message: String)
    }

    class MvcModel {
        var counter: Int
        var message: String {
            didSet {
                delegate?.didUpDateModel(message: message)
            }
        }
        var delegate: MvcModelDelegate?

        init(counter: Int, message: String) {
            self.counter = counter
            self.message = message
        }
    }

    // create instance
    var model = MvcModel(counter: 0, message: "" )

    // counting
    func incrementCounter() {
        model.counter += 1
        model.message = "Counter Value:  \(model.counter)"
    }
}
```

View Controller File

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController, ModelDelegate {
    // communication link to the model
    var model1 = model
    var messageFromModel = messageToLabel

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.model1.delegate = self
    }

    // update display
    func didUpdateModel(message: String) {
        //self.Label1.stringValue = model1.message
        self.Label1.stringValue = messageFromModel
    }

    // Label
    @IBOutlet weak var Label1: NSTextField! {
        didSet {
            Label1.stringValue = " counter not started"
        }
    }

    // Button
    @IBAction func testButton(_ sender: NSButton) {
        incrementCounter()
    }    
}
```

Comment: @Noam - I tried to modify the model to move it from a class to a struct doing a few adjustments in the model file ( no change at the view controller file). As soon as I change class by struct the program no longer works. In fact it looks like the "delegate?.didUpdateModel(message: message)" is not executed as the delegate value is nil. I guess the problem is that I do not declare/initialize the delegate property correctly.

What would you suggest to correct that? Any idea of a book that covers those topics in details and clarity?